# Python ImageGrab Not Working With Input

Tags: python, input, screenshot

In my program, I'm taking a screenshot of a part of my screen, which works. But when I add anything in front of calling the function it's in, it no longer gets past the ImageGrab part.

This works:

```
def takePictures():
    print("3")
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("1")
        im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(760, 250, 1160, 680))  # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
        print("2")
        im.save('ALL.png')
        #im.show()
 takePictures()
```

This doesn't:

```
def takePictures():
    print("3")
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("1")
        im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(760, 250, 1160, 680))  # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
        #^^^ Doesnt get past this line
        print("2")
        im.save('ALL.png')
        #im.show()
if input() == "":
    takePictures()
```

I've also tried it with inputs from keys on a different window and it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your program will pause at

```
if input() == "":
    takePictures()
```

until you activate the python executing window and hit the enter key.

If you want to take screen shots, you can use, say

```
time.sleep(10)
```

giving yourself 10 seconds to activate the window you want to take a screen shot of.